# PHP : dynamic instance with not fully-qualified namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I'd like to instanciate my class doing :

```
use somedir\http as Http;

$S_bodyWriterType  = 'Http\\' . strtolower($S_requestBodyPayloadType) . '\\RequestBodyWriter';
$this->_O_requestBodyWriter = new $S_bodyWriterType;
```

It says the class does not exist. However THAT would work (no string involved here) :

```
$this->_O_requestBodyWriter = new Http\xml\RequestBodyWriter;
```

And that would also work of course (the namespace is fully qualified) :

```
$S_bodyWriterType  = 'somedir\http\\' . strtolower($S_requestBodyPayloadType) . '\\' . 'RequestBodyWriter';
$this->_O_requestBodyWriter = new $S_bodyWriterType;
```

i'd definitely prefer to use shortened namespaces instead of having to write long, fully-qualified namespaces in different places of the codebase and having to change them all in case the directory location moves. I've been pulling my hair off for a while now over this.

Thanks for help !

Comment: "It says the class does not exist." => Which class? Show us the error message. Anyway, you save just 8 characters (`somedir\`). You can set a constant for it (feels a little bit cleaner too ;)).

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Http\xml\RequestBodyWriter' not found...And well, yes, I was considering using a constant as a work around. I stumbled across that comment "When used as a string we need the fully qualified name as we don't know where the parameter is coming from." on http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51126. I guess it's the same for dynamic instantiations with strings...

Answer (score 0):

OK, you provided the [Bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51126) yourself ;) But thats the fact: If you define a classname in a string, its not said, that the object is created in the same context.

```
namespace y {
  use a\b as B;
  $GLOBALS['class'] = 'B\\MyClass';
}
namespace z {
  use k\l as B;
  $classname = $GLOBALS['class'];
  $a = new $classname;
}
```

Thus you need to define classnames in string full qualifed. I suggest to use (namespace-/class-)constants

```
use a\b as B;
const NAMESPACE_B = '\\a\\b';
$classname = NAMESPACE_B . '\\MyClass';
```

If the class you want to instanciate is in a subnamespace, remember, that the pseudo-constant `__NAMESPACE__` always exists;

```
namespace a;
use a\b as B;
$classname = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\b\\MyClass';
```

Additional in your case I suggest to create a factory

```
use somedir\http as Http;
class RequestBodyWriterFactory {
  public function create($type) {
    $classname = __NAMESPACE__ . "\\$type\\RequestBodyWriter";
    return new $classname;
  }
}

// somewere else
$this->_O_requestBodyWriter = $this->factory->create(strtolower($S_requestBodyPayloadType));
```

This way you have more control on what is created and how its created.